# Is there any possible way to map the name of foreign key in reference table? (ManyToMany)

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jdbc

I tried to implement a reference table when it comes to ManyToMany relation in the context of DDD based on this article(https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates)

I have different naming for JdbcEntity because I have another Domain Entity named `Book` which handles domain logic. (I've decided to decouple `Domain model` and `Persistence model` which is `JdbcEntity` as below)

The problem is the class name `BookJdbcEntity` is mapped as a foreign key name in `book_author` automatically:

```
"PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT `book_author`.`AUTHOR_ID` AS `AUTHOR_ID` FROM `book_author` WHERE `book_author`.`BOOK_JDBC_ENTITY` = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=845) Unknown column 'book_author.BOOK_JDBC_ENTITY' in 'where clause'",
```

Is there any possible way to generate the below SQL statement? (`book_id` instead of `BOOK_JDBC_ENTITY`)

```
SELECT `book_author`.`AUTHOR_ID` AS `AUTHOR_ID` FROM `book_author` WHERE `book_author`.`book_id` = ?
```

Jdbc Entity:

```
@Table("book")
data class BookJdbcEntity(
    @Id val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val isbn: String,
    val pages: Int,
    val authors: Set<AuthorRef> = hashSetOf()
)

@Table("book_author")
data class AuthorRef(val authorId: Long)
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book
(
    id    bigint(20)   NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    isbn  varchar(100) not null,
    pages INTEGER      not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book_author
(
    book_id   bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    author_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    constraint book_id_fk foreign key (book_id) references book (id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done with [`@MappedCollection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.2.0/api/org/springframework/data/relational/core/mapping/MappedCollection.html)

```kotlin
@Table("book")
data class BookJdbcEntity(
    @Id val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val isbn: String,
    val pages: Int,
    @MappedCollection(idColumn="book_id")
    val authors: Set<AuthorRef> = hashSetOf()
)
```